# Angular Nested conditions using ng-switch

Tags: angularjs

Is it possible to have a root first condition been evaluated using ng-show, ng-if  or ng-switch  before a series of second tier conditions are evaluated using ng-switch

```
<div ng-if="firstcondition = 'true'" >
   <div ng-switch="secondCondition">
      <div ng-switch-when="0">
         <div ng-include="'firstview.html'"></div>
      </div>
      <div ng-switch-when="2">
         <div ng-include="'secondView.html'"></div>
      </div>
      <div ng-switch-when="3">
         <div ng-include="'thirdView.html'"></div>
      </div>
   </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Have you tried this? Did it work? If no, why not? Did you get an error? If yes, which?

Comment: they work in isolation    but not together  not sure why ?

Comment: Does putting `{{ secondCondition }}` between the `ng-if` and `ng-switch` give you any output?

Answer (score 1):

Your error point is here

```
<div ng-if="firstcondition = 'true'" >
```

This should be this

```
<div ng-if="firstcondition == 'true'" >
```

Your are using single `=` sign which is use for assigning.